# apply CountVectorized to whole data before applying train_test_split

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, text-mining

Is there any difference between the two different snips of codes.

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
xtrain_count =  count_vect.fit_transform(train_X)
xvalid_count =  count_vect.fit_transform(valid_X)
```

and fitting it first to the whole dataset 
`count_vect.fit(trainDF['text'])`
and then apply:

```
xtrain_count =  count_vect.transform(train_X)
xvalid_count =  count_vect.transform(valid_X)
```

I am interested in the results. I understand the difference in the code i.e., the fit and transform. Is the second case where you fit it first to the whole dataset better? Last question: Is the same if I do the TfidfVectorizer or in this case it is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one, you `fit` to the validation/test set, that you should never do. For example, if your validation set contains a couple of different words than your training set, you'd get different vectors. As in your second example, first fit to training set, then transform any data given using that corpus.

Comment: Just to understand this better, the definition of CountVectorizer is: Convert a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts. I do not see exactly what is the underlying relationship that needs to learn.

Comment: `fit` method learns the vocabulary set. `transform` counts the tokens in *this* vocabulary set. If you fit to different data, there is a chance that your vocabulary sets will be different.